# AngularFire2 (Firebase) Check if user is logged in

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I found today this awesome Google Service (Firebase) and try some stuff with it. I Implement in my App the Auth and it works like a charm. But i cant find a Documentation for Angular. I got 2 Buttons (Login and Logout) and i want to Hide ore show them depends on auth status (Logged in or not Logged in)

I do it in this way:

```
<button *ngIf="!(user | async)?.uid" (click)="login()">Login</button>
<button *ngIf="(user | async)?.uid" (click)="logout()">Logout</button>
```

But i am very sure that this way is not correct. It Works but it looks little dirty. i am sure they got any shorter variable that i can use. but i dont find any. I just find a old Tutorial where the Author write: *ngIf="(afAuth.auth | async)" But this code snipped dont work for me.

Comment: have you solved this problem??